# invalid Syntax near '?' error

Tags: vb.net

I have converted my database from MS Access to SQL Server. So while saving image it throws this error. How can I solve this?

This is my code:

```
SelStr = "" &
          "Update Admission Set AdmissionNo = '" & AdmNo & "', ENClass = '" & Enclass & "', StudentFN = '" & SFN & "', " &
          "StudentMN = '" & SMN & "', StudentLN = '" & SLN & "', FatherFN = '" & FFN & "', FatherMN = '" & FMN & "', " &
          "FatherLN = '" & FLN & "', MotherFN = '" & MFN & "', MotherMN = '" & MMN & "', MotherLN = '" & MLN & "', " &
          "GuardianFN = '" & GFN & "', GuardianLN = '" & GLN & "', GRelation = '" & GRel & "', CCity = '" & CCity & "', " &
          "FatMob = '" & FathMo & "', AltNo = '" & AltNo & "', Gender =  '" & Gender & "', Category = '" & Category & "', " &
          "Religion = '" & Religion & "', PSName = '" & PSName & "', PSClass = '" & PSClass & "', PSGrade = '" & PSGrade & "', " &
          "PSCity = '" & PSCity & "', PSState = '" & PSState & "', PSPYear = '" & PSYear & "', AddressPer = '" & AddPer & "', " &
          "AddressPre = '" & AddPre & "', Remark = '" & Remark & "', DOB = '" & DOB & "', JnDt = '" & JnDt & "', " &
          "FOcc = '" & Focc & "', FEdu = '" & FEdu & "', FASal = '" & FASal & "', MOcc ='" & MOcc & "', MEdu = '" & MEdu & "', " &
          "MASal = '" & MASal & "', BusFacility = '" & BusFac & "', BusFrmID=0 , BusFrm = 'NA', " &
          "BroSis = '" & BroSis & "', Attachments = '" & AttachLis & "', AttachmentIDs = '" & AttIDs & "', MotMob = '" & MothMo & "', " &
          "[Cast] = '" & SCast & "', SMSNo = '" & SMSNo & "',Student_Images=" & strImage & ",SType = '" & SType & "',Email = '" & Email & "',Aadhar = '" & Aadhar & "' Where AdmissionID = " & temp & ""

    cmd.CommandText = SelStr

    If strImage = "?" Then
        cmd.Parameters.Add(strImage, SqlDbType.Image).Value = arrImage
    End If

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

Comment: Beware of little bobby tables. Throw that code away and start working with parameterized queries.

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should ***N-O-T*** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection

Comment: Sweet! `String`, the universal data type. [#DuctTape](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duct_tape)

Answer (score 0):

```
If strImage = "?" Then
        cmd.Parameters.Add(strImage,
```

You shouldn't use a parameter name of '?'

(and I agree with Zohar).